# PowerBI not showing date on X Axis?

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset that looks something like this

[image]

I want to plot a given "owners" spend over time. So basically I want to groupby owner and plot their total spend throughout the year. However when I try to do this in powerBI it wants to put the owners on the X Axis for some reason. Normally in Excel you can address this by simply selecting "swap axis" but don't see a way to do that in powerbi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the Visualizations pane (on the right) and select the Fields button (a white bar chart icon, beneath the table of Visualization types), then you can drag the data fields into any "Field Well" (e.g. Axis, Legend, Value).

That said, I suspect that you will need to reshape your data back in the Query layer, using an Unpivot transformation to cover the monthly columns (e.g. Jul-15, Aug-15 etc) into a pair of Attribute (Month) and Value ($) columns.  This will allow charting Months on an Axis and filtering by date (e.g. last 6 months).